# Number of vertices in a planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, planar-graphs

For which values of $k$ can you prove the following statement? There exists an $n$ such that any planar graph on at least n vertices contains at least $k$ vertices of degree at most $5$. Could it hold for every $k$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You are more likely to get useful help on this site if you explain what you've tried so far, where you are stuck. Otherwise you are likely to get downvoted or have your question closed.

Comment: I can think of one family of planar graphs with $3n$ vertices of degree $6$ and $6$ vertices of degree $2$, so $k>6$ certainly won't work.

Comment: ... and of another family with $2n(n-2)$ vertices of degree $6$ and $4$ vertices of degree $3$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763598/every-planar-graph-has-a-vertex-of-degree-at-most-5

Comment: @HenningMakholm: were you thinking to [similar objects](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A120dcccT)?

Comment: There also is [a class of planar graphs](http://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/?recipe=A120dccccC) with $4^n-4$ vertices of degree $6$ and $6$ vertices of degree $4$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I can't quite discern what's going on a the tips but the tetrahedral example looks like what I was envisaging in my second comment.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Such a tiling can't exist. If we tile a sphere (of Euler characteristic $2$) with $n$ hexagons and $k$ pentagons, meeting in threes at the corners, then we have $\frac13(6n+5k)$ vertices and $\frac12(6n+5k)$ edges. Inserting that into $V-E+F=2$, a bit of algebra produces $k=12$.

Comment: An extension of this argument: Given a planar graph where all faces are triangles, let the "defect" of a vertex be $6$ minus its degree. $V-E+F$ now implies that the _total_ defect must be exactly $12$. Since a vertex in a triangular graph (other than $C_3$) cannot have degree less than $3$, there must be at least $4$ vertices with degree less than $6$.

Answer (score 3):

**Summary**: $k=4$ is the largest $k$.  We can eliminate $k \leq 2$ using Euler's Formula and the Handshaking Lemma.  We can eliminate $k=3$ with some case analysis.  And when $k=4$, there's a construction of a family of planar graphs with $n-4$ degree-$6$ vertices and $4$ degree-$3$ vertices.

---

A graph with $q:=n-k$ vertices of degree $\geq 6$ has at least $\tfrac{1}{2} 6q=3q$ edges, by the [Handshaking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).  [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula) thus implies that a $n$-vertex planar graph has $3q \leq 3n-6$, or equivalently $q \leq n-2$.  This proves $k \geq 2$.

If $k=2$ and the small degrees are $d_1$ and $d_2$, then by bounding the sum of the degrees, we get
$$
6(n-2)+d_1+d_2 \leq 2e \leq 6n-12
$$
which implies $d_1$ and $d_2$ are both $0$.  We can delete these two isolated vertices to contradict Euler's Formula.  So $k \geq 3$.

If $k=3$ and the small degrees are $d_1$, $d_2$, and $d_3$, then $$6(n-3)+d_1+d_2+d_3 \leq 2e \leq 6n-12.$$  That is, $d_1+d_2+d_3 \leq 6$.

If we have an isolated vertex, we delete it and end up back in the $k=2$ case.  If we have a vertex of degree $2$, we can contract it with one of its neighbors, and end up back in the $k=2$ case.  Either way, we reach a contradiction.

If we have a vertex of degree $1$ then...  If its neighbor has degree other than $6$, than we can delete the degree-$1$ vertex and end up in the $k=2$ or $k=1$ case, reaching a contradiction.  Otherwise, we still delete it, but we remain in the $k=3$ case, but with a degree-$5$ vertex, but then we contradict $d_1+d_2+d_3 \leq 6$.

Thus $d_1$, $d_2$, and $d_3$ are all at least $3$, contradicting $d_1+d_2+d_3 \leq 6$.

Hence $k \geq 4$.

Finally, I think the construction Henning Makholm and Jack D'Aurizio seem to be talking about in the comments is:

1. Take a tetrahedron,
2. subdivide each edge once, and
3. connect newly created vertices that share a face that was on the original tetrahedron.

Then repeat steps 2 and 3.  (Projecting onto a sphere or plane as desired.)  Here's an attempt at a drawing:

[image]

We always create vertices of degree $6$, and we have exactly $4$ vertices of degree $3$.  Thus construction implies $k \leq 4$.